# QueryDSL NoSuchMethodError: jpa.JPQLQuery.from()

Tags: spring-data-jpa, nosuchmethoderror, querydsl

Trying to get Query Dsl (version 3.1.1) and Spring Data JPA (version 1.3.1.RELEASE) up and running..

My problem is with this error message ...

```
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysema.query.jpa.JPQLQuery.from([Lcom/mysema/query/types/EntityPath;)Lcom/mysema/query/jpa/JPQLCommonQuery;
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.Querydsl.createQuery(Querydsl.java:88)
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.createQuery(QueryDslJ  paRepository.java:131)
```

Seems to be like a version compatibility conflict. But what version of QueryDSL should I use for Spring Data JPA 1.3.1.RELEASE?

I was hoping to find the answer [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.3.1.RELEASE.pom) but I couldn't see what is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what version of QueryDSL should I use for Spring Data JPA 1.3.1.RELEASE?

Querydsl 2.9

Comment: Tx Timo, have been struggling with this for two days now. I'll come back to my other two questions later.