# Spring Boot app with Spring Data cannot find com.mysema.query.types EntityPath

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data, pom.xml

On July 30, 2015 our Spring Boot application was working fine, but when we tried running it on August 3, 2015 it failed with this error:

```
13:16:33.981 [org.directoryx.Application.main()] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication 
- Application startup failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysema/query/types/EntityPath
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:606)
    ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RC2.jar:4.2.0.RC2]...
```

We noticed the the Spring Framework had a new release within that time frame. We tried updating our Spring Boot dependency from 1.3.0.M1 to 1.3.0.M2 but that did not fix the issue.

See the [full POM](https://bitbucket.org/rigorous/directoryx/src/a696ee5e1aa065f6208328b955cecf4ca328e9a2/pom.xml?at=master) for more details.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Google shows multiple links for this particular NoClassDefFoundError: they all point to JPA version.  Look here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218100

Answer (score 0):

The dependency graph and *effective POM* in Intellij IDEA shows: **Spring 4.2.0.RC2**

Setting 4.2.0.RELEASE version explicitly in the properties of the POM seems to resolve the problem:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```